# What kind of checks and warnings does React.StrictMode activate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From React documentation on React.StrictMode and React.Fragment: 
 [Both Fragment, StrictMode does not render any visible UI. It activates additional checks and warnings for its descendants.](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

**Question: What kind of checks and warnings does React.StrictMode activate on this code?**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function About() {
    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <h1>About page</h1>
            <p>This is a text deescribing the About page</hp>
        </React.StrictMode>
    )
}
```

Comment: Did you read the five points starting *"StrictMode currently helps with:"*? The whole rest of the article you've linked explains exactly what kinds of things it detects.

Comment: Oh my bad! I didn't read through the article. Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

The [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) you linked states exactly what it helps with:

> StrictMode currently helps with:
>
> - Identifying components with unsafe lifecycles
> - Warning about legacy string ref API usage
> - Warning about deprecated findDOMNode usage
> - Detecting unexpected side effects
> - Detecting legacy context API